# SSL error when trying to perform Flask tutorial in Windows

Tags: python, flask

trying to complete the basic flask tutorial. I am running windows, have Anaconda as my python instance, and have flask installed and mapped to my environment paths. However, when running 'flask run' within CMD, i receive the following error:

```
C:\Users\Will\Dropbox\Python\portfolio\flask-tutorial>flask run
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Will\Anaconda3\Scripts\flask-script.py", line 9, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "C:\Users\Will\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\cli.py", line 966, in main
    cli.main(prog_name="python -m flask" if as_module else None)
  File "C:\Users\Will\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\cli.py", line 586, in main
    return super(FlaskGroup, self).main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Will\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 717, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\Will\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1135, in invoke
    sub_ctx = cmd.make_context(cmd_name, args, parent=ctx)
  File "C:\Users\Will\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 641, in make_context
    self.parse_args(ctx, args)
  File "C:\Users\Will\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 940, in parse_args
    value, args = param.handle_parse_result(ctx, opts, args)
  File "C:\Users\Will\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1477, in handle_parse_result
    self.callback, ctx, self, value)
  File "C:\Users\Will\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 96, in invoke_param_callback
    return callback(ctx, param, value)
  File "C:\Users\Will\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\flask\cli.py", line 742, in _validate_key
    is_context = isinstance(cert, ssl.SSLContext)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'SSLContext'
```

What would inspire an SSL error, and is there an easy way to locate this cert?

Comment: this may [help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61162227/attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-sslcontext-running-flask-sc)

Answer (score 0):

I found that because i was using the conda environment, i had to do the following and it worked:

```
conda activate base
```